# DHCP and DNS client in Linux

Tags: dns, dhcp

I am trying to make the linux/ubuntu handle dhcp and dns for me. What I do want is getting ip address from the dhcp server, and register it to the dns server. It will update the dns server when achieved an new IP address and when it is not it will keep updating the dns server in every X sec.

How can I implement these features?

What I have tried is dhcpcd and ddclient in ubuntu. Here is my dhcpcd.conf in /etc/:

```
hostname exp.mydomain.com
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identier
slaac_private
interface eth0
# same result with fqdn or not.
fqdn both
```

and my ddclient is default except for the hostname being same in the dhcpcd.conf. What I assumed is when dhcpcd achieved an IP address from the dhcp server it will do a register based on the hostname that I gave in the dhcpcd.conf to the dns server. Although I did not find any DNS register under that hostname and couldn't find any with nslookup command. After trying ddclient I have achieved same results but it was something different when I lookup with nslookup exp.mydomain.com I have seen the old IP address received from the DHCP server but again I did not see any DNS record at dns server.